# changing the mysql code to list all images in a one row by comma separator

Tags: mysql

I the code for the two tables where `PRODUCTID` is JOINED as the FK in the images table and he other table is the products table which has the `ProductID` as PK

Based upon above, I am joining the query as like this

```
   SELECT
    products.menuName,
    products.menuid,
    products.menuDisplayName,
    CONCAT(menuName,'^', menuDisplayName) AS combinedData,
    images.image
    FROM
    products
    LEFT OUTER JOIN images ON products.menuid = images.ProductID
    where 1=1
```

The query is working fine, all i am trying is, if the product has images, i should be in the image column as comma separated list

Comment: Why? :-( so depressing

Comment: what was that, answer, depression ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   SELECT
    products.menuName,
    products.menuid,
    products.menuDisplayName,
    CONCAT(menuName,'^', menuDisplayName) AS combinedData,
    group_concat(images.image)
    FROM
    products
    LEFT JOIN images ON products.menuid = images.ProductID
    group by 2
```